# Stanford tutorial Flickr app URL Changes

Tags: ios, json, rest, flickr

I'm following the stanford tutorial for shutterbug app that queries flickr photos. The queryURL I suppose has been changed as when I try this:

```
NSURL *url = [FlickrFetcher URLforRecentGeoreferencedPhotos];
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
NSDictionary *dictionary = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:NULL];
NSLog(@"JSON data is %@",dictionary);
```

The output I get is

```
JSON data is {
code = 100;
message = "Invalid API Key (Key has invalid format)";
stat = fail;
}
```

I dont understand how to retrieve such URL's from any website to query its information. (REST in this case).

Comment: If you get an answer this clear the URL is probably okay. You need a valid API key. The tutorial probably uses something like `NSString *apiKey = @"YourAPIKeyHere";` in the code and you forgot to replace that placeholder with an actual key.

Comment: How do I get the actual key?

Answer (score 0):

The URL is probably alright. As you can see in the message the API complains that your API key has a wrong format.

The Project should contain a file named `FlickrAPIKey.h` in the `Flickr Fetcher` folder/group. It has the following content:

```
//
//  FlickrAPIKey.h
//
//  Created for Stanford CS193p Fall 2013.
//  Copyright 2013 Stanford University. All rights reserved.
//
//  Get your own key!
//  No Flickr fetches will work without the API Key!
//

#define FlickrAPIKey @""
```

You have to get your own API key from flickr and put it in there.
e.g.: `#define FlickrAPIKey @"MyFancyAPIKey"`

A quick trip to Google ("get flickr api key") revealed that you can request your key in Flickr's ["App Garden"](https://www.flickr.com/services/apps/create/)

Comment: Yeah I figured that, how do I get the URL ?

Comment: I did get the key now, and using it I got an error saying:
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'data parameter is nil'

Answer (score 0):

You should get your own [API key here](https://www.flickr.com/services/apps/create/apply/). Then update  file with your key.

**Please make sure your request starts with https** since [Flickr has changed its api SSL only on June 27th, 2014](http://code.flickr.net/2014/04/30/flickr-api-going-ssl-only-on-june-27th-2014/).